# Display how css is being added inline from javascript

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to find out how some inline css is being added to my html when the page is scrolled down.

I am using chrome dev tools. I think it is supposed to be in console, but I don't see anything show up in there when I scroll the page and know that the javascript is being fired. I assume it is javascript.

When I scroll down the page the header size shrinks to a set amount of pixels. I want to change that number but I can't find the source of what is causing the change.

Comment: Post a code sample, or link to live code. You'll need to search the javascript, nothing will show up in the console (in this case) unless the code says to log something there.

Comment: It sounds like a plugin. Comment out your scripts one-by-one to see which one is causing the inlining css.

Comment: Ok I was hoping there would be a way to see which script is causing the inlines css without having to search. I guess I am lazy.

Answer (score 0):

- Inspect element that gets inline styles set.
- Right click on it in the `Elements` tab.
- Choose `Break on.. -> Attributes Modification`.

[image: DevTools > Elements Tab > Break on.. > Attributes Modification]

- Scroll the page.
- JavaScript execution will stop on line that modifies any of the attributes (including 'style').
- If you'll end up in the middle of jQuery/Angular/etc. - look at the `Call Stack` in the `Sources Panel`. It should reveal the higher-level code that modifies the styles.

[image: DevTools > Sources Tab > Call Stack]